# Manager telling me I should not contact Human resources / possible fraud

Tags: management, human-resources

I work in a charity store as a full time store assistant,  I have been told by my manager that I should not contact human resources for details of my contract which I have still not been given after being with them for more than 6 months, and that it is company policy that any contact with human resources has to go through them, and they have not done so after me asking several times.

I also have several concerns that the same manager is involved in fraudulent activities to meet targets and to claim money from the petty cash for volunteer travel expenses when they are not entitled to it.

Examples:

- I am told that I should remove what is known as gift aid from old garments and use them on items that have not been gift aided, and to use remaining Gift aid stickers on items that have been donated, but not gift aided.  (Definite Fraud)
- Told that I should use their partners name, and fill out a Gift aid form, and use the Gift aid stickers on stock.  (Fraud?)
- Told not to put some items through the till, but to take the money and put it into the donation tub then use that money later on to meet sales targets.  (pretty sure this too is Fraud)
- Using single use (£3), and Week long (£18) bus tickets to claim travel expenses then give that money to a volunteer who walks. (embezzlement?)

What can I do ?  This is my first job after a long period of unemployment, and as such I can not afford to loose it without having another one lined up, so walking out is not an option.

Comment: Difficult to say if it is fraud or not. If you believe it is then most HR departments have a anonymous tip line that you call. If not, then it sounds like you are in the UK and from what I understand there is a specific government department that handles these sort of claims.

Comment: I don't believe this is the place for seeking legal advice, but if you have a close friend or relative, who is a lawyer, or have access to a lawyer free of charge, seek legal advice. What you said doesn't only smell but wreaks fraud and criminal activity, even though I am in the US

Comment: Hi Dan,   I have thought about making an anonymous tip, however it would be pretty clear who had called them due to me being the only member of staff in the store, and the manager in question would know instantly that it was me, putting my job at risk.  If you know of the Government department name, I would happily look into contact them.

Comment: Hi  MelBurslan, I don't know any family members in the legal profession, but seeking legal advice is something I may actually consider after the amount of verbal abuse I got from the person in question for not wanting to do as they asked regarding the Gift Aid.

Comment: @Concernedemployee Unfortunately I do not know enough about UK to answer what the name of the agency is. I do not live in the UK but have heard of agencies that protect workers and frauds. With this being a charity I'd imagine any fraud claims would be taken very seriously.

Comment: I take it that (since it's large enough to have an HR department) this is a larger charity with many shops?  Then my first step would be to call HR anonymously, and ask if it is indeed company policy.

Comment: `it is company policy that any contact with human resources has to go through them` I call BS. Try to verify that if you have an employee handbook. Regardless, don't be too overt about contacting HR (and you absolutely __should__ contact them to get your contract details). They'll let you know if you violated that company "policy".

Comment: Definitely talk to HR. Also, I'm sure that there's a labor ministry or some such thing you could contact, however none of us here are legal experts. I think looking for a new job is _definitely_ the best idea at this point. Good luck.

Comment: Does giving a volunteer £18 per week really matter. One assumes that they are on benefits and therefore have the time to walk. That £18 is a small fee for there efforts.

Answer (score 6):

If this is in the UK (which I assume base on 'gift aid') you should receive a *written statement of employment particulars* if you are working for your employer for more than 1 month. [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions/written-statement-of-employment-particulars)

It is a legal requirement and you should contact your employers HR department to give them a chance to correct this oversight.

As for your manager if you feel you should report his behaviour you can contact HR if you want, or anonymously report it to [ActionFraud](http://www.actionfraud.police.uk).

Answer (score 4):

Look for another job, and raise your suspicions with the relevant authorities immediately. Then let the cards fall where they may. You are complicit if you have strong suspicions of illegal activity and do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't afford to lose the job, then you need to stop complaining. Having said that, you really need to get out and find another job.

Charity organisations tend to be ridden with this sort of dodgy business practices. By their nature they attract well meaning but often totally unsuitable people who quite quickly find themselves in over their heads. And they also have a happy go lucky attitude towards the finances quite often. They are often very political and HR and your boss may be connected in ways outside work since charities tend (here anyway) to comprise a lot of interconnected people.

If I were you I would get out, you've had 6 months you could have used looking for other jobs, don't waste any more time. Keep this job until you can get out, then don't look back. I wouldn't bother over petty issues like you mentioned, just make sure no dirt sticks to me on the way out the door.

Comment: I think the first paragraph is unhelpful and unnecessary.

Comment: I'm being pragmatic rather than touchy feely sorry. Anyone in your position is easier to force out onto the road, then the domino effect of investigating a charity where all sorts of well connected people might have their hand in the till in different ways. I've seen it happen more than once. The whistle blower hung out to dry while the perpetrators carry on.